# Dropdown of bootstrap does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This my html file. I am adding this file to ng-view. But the drop down does not seem to work.

```
<button style="background-color: transparent; border: none" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Admin
  <span class="caret"></span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</button>
```

These are the necessary css and js files needed for my application. I have a single page application so I am adding above html code to this using ng-view

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/commons/constants.js"></script>
<!-- Directives scripts -->

<script src="/javascripts/directives/passwordpattern.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/directives/passwordstrength.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts for authentication-->
<script src="/javascripts/services/AuthService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/AuthController.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts for Trucks -->
<script src="/javascripts/services/TruckService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/TrucksController.js"></script>
<!-- Scripts for customers -->
<script src="/javascripts/services/CustomerService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
<!-- Scripts for Admin -->
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/AdminController.js"></script>

<!--<script data-main="/javascripts/main.js" src="/javascripts/vendor/require-2.2.0.js"></script>-->

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/smallicons-logotypes/32/amazon-16.png"/>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

<!-- <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zxcvbn/4.2.0/zxcvbn.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does not seem to work?

Comment: U have to include Boostrap script: 

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @chan, uncomment your link `maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js` instead `netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button style="background-color: transparent; border: none" class=dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" >Admin
                <span class="caret"></span> 
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As reported from "Libor Zahrádka" you need to include the bootstrap javascript library:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/commons/constants.js"></script>
<!-- Directives scripts -->

<script src="/javascripts/directives/passwordpattern.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/directives/passwordstrength.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts for authentication-->
<script src="/javascripts/services/AuthService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/AuthController.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts for Trucks -->
<script src="/javascripts/services/TruckService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/TrucksController.js"></script>
<!-- Scripts for customers -->
<script src="/javascripts/services/CustomerService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
<!-- Scripts for Admin -->
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/AdminController.js"></script>

<!--<script data-main="/javascripts/main.js" src="/javascripts/vendor/require-2.2.0.js"></script>-->

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/smallicons-logotypes/32/amazon-16.png"/>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.material.min.css"/>




<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="dropdown">
    <button style="background-color: transparent; border: none" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
            type="button">Admin
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```